# problema con PhotImage en tkinter de python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

pues resulta que estoy conociendo el úso de canvas y cuando quiero insertar una imágen al widget ocúrre esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

éste el el código que estoy practicando:

```
import tkinter

top = tkinter.Toplevel ()

can = tkinter.Canvas (top , bg ="gray" , height =500 , width =500)
image_1 = tkinter.PhotoImage (file =" ")

image = can.create_image (200 , 200 , image = image_1)

can.pack ()

top.mainloop ()
```

Comment: ¿Puedes describir mejor que problema tienes y que quieres obtener?

Comment: sí andyio,  según éste código la imágen debería aparecer integrada en la ventana pequeña del widget que se ve en la captura, pero se ábren dos ventanas.  el resultado debería ser que la imágen aparezca dentro de una sola ventana de widget y por supuesto, debería de aparecer un sólo widget.

Comment: Deberías darle las mismas dimensiones a la imagen que a la ventana en la que deseas que aparezca, con los parámetros `height` y `width` en la variable `image`

Comment: bueno, agregué los parámetros que me aconsejáste. no ha funcionado lamentáblemente.

Comment: seguiré probrando pues de yapa en el manual no díce nada sobre este fállo.

Comment: Echale un vistazo a esto https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-add-images-in-tkinter/, además deberías mirarte la librería PIL https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

Comment: bueno, con pillow tengo un problema similar tambien, ajaj. gracias, leeré el link.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tiene es muy simple, si usted está agregando una ventana hija y no estableciendo la ventana principal o comúnmente el `root`, la imagen no es el problema, el problema es que usted está agregando una ventana hija o `Toplevel` y por lo tanto la imagen no se mostrará en el Toplevel y se mostrará en una ventana adicional no definida como ventana principal.

Una recomendación es que use el módulo Pillow para ubicar con facilidad la imagen en la interfaz. Si solo quiere establecer la imagen en la ventana pequeña, es claro que al ser una ventana dependiente de la ventana padre, usted no puede quitar la ventana inicial o el `root` y solo dejar el Toplevel.

Acabo de probar su código y es lógico usted no estableció la ventana principal, si quiere lograr ubicar su imagen en el Toplevel, le recomiendo que use el módulo Pillow para más facilidad y de igual forma establecer en el Toplevel la imagen. Un ejemplo similar sería el siguiente:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image # Importar modulo Pillow como Image de manera simplificada

root = tk.Tk()

labelInfo = tk.Label(root, text='Esto es la ventana principal', font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), fg='black')
labelInfo.place(x=8,y=9)


labelInfo = tk.Label(root, font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), bg='grey', height=50, width=50)
labelInfo.place(x=8,y=30)

top = tkinter.Toplevel ()

image = Image.open("imagePython.png") # Especifque su imagen, en este caso es un ejemplo de una imagen que puse

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

labelImage = tk.Label(top, image=img) # Label para ubicar la imagen
labelImage.place(x=5, y=9) 

labelInfo = tk.Label(top, text='Esto es una imagen en otra\nventana secundaria:', font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), fg='black')
labelInfo.place(x=8,y=9)

top.focus_force()
top.focus_set()
top.transient(root)
top.grab_set() # Manetener el foco de inicio obligando la ventana inicial a estar inactiva
top.mainloop() # Fin ciclo de eventos del Toplevel


root.mainloop() #Fin ciclo de eventos principal, si se destruye el Toplevel se destruye
```

Así quedaría el ejemplo en mi caso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este ejemplo usa la versión Python 3.5.3 y Pillow versión 7.2.0

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicación y el ejemplo. no me a funcionado, instalé pillow con pip pero no carga al editor de texto importándolo. seguiré investigando. gracias.

Comment: Si no le funciono la solución más viable es que verifique la versión de Python que tiene instalada para poder buscar una solución ya que a veces por usar una versión incorrecta de algún modulo puede que se instale pero al momento de importar no va a servir o puede mostrar error, esto ya me sucedió con Python 3.4 use un modulo de una versión incorrecta y no servía aunque este importado.

Comment: finalmente solucionado. PIL y pillow no pueden estar en el mismo entorno, asi que reinstalé pillow, lo actualicé con pip y finalmente encontré el comando pip requests que sírve para compatibilizar pillow con python. gracias

Comment: Me alegra haya podido solucionar su problema y encontrar el error.